# Why are files in /lib/firmware not compressed?

Tags: ubuntu, firmware

While upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 I noticed that /lib/firmware is huge: >800 MB (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-firmware)

I assume this package contains binary blobs for all sorts of hardware. This means that on any given system only very few of these files will actually be used.

Which brings me to the question: Why are they not compressed?

I perfectly understand that when you buy a new gadget you want it to work just by plugging it in - you do not want to mess around with downloading firmware to get it working. So I understand why Ubuntu has chosen to include firmware for "everything". But it puzzles me why the files are installed uncompressed: We compress man-pages because today they are faster to open and take up less space if they are compressed. Many of the files in /lib/firmware easily compress to <50%. Is there a technical reason why you could not simply decompress the (few) files that you actually need?

Comment: This is being addressed but very slowly: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1942260

Comment: Speaking of me: I don't have this package installed at all. I've installed only the required firmware files and I feel great. Occasionally I update them from linux-firmware.git repo. `du -hs /lib/firmware -> 14M`. You also don't need to update all these files each time a new package gets released (which is crazy as both RPM and DEB are unable to check whether files are actually being updated and only updated the changed ones - at least RPM will have this fixed in Fedora 36).

Comment: Lastly `xz` is a very bad format for compression as it's relatively expensive and slow to decompress. Use ZSTD instead whanever possible. It can be up to 20 times faster at decompression. It's only mildly worse in terms of compression ratio.

Comment: `xz` shines when you have gigabytes of similar data to compress and you can use a large dictionary (for `7zz` (native 7z for Linux, p7zip has been long unmaintained) it's now `3840MB`).